# Warning: Unable to merge @OA\Post(), Zircote, PHP

Tags: php, swagger

I am using zircote/swagger-php, but I am getting this error:

`Warning: Unable to merge @OA\Post() ...`

Can't understand why, and it is doing something bad to the final swagger.json, because some schemas are not recognizable. Like:

`Definition was declared but never used in document`

Let's see some code:

```
    /**
     * @OA\POST(
     *     path="/delete",
     *     summary="Delete Evidences Request",
     *     description="Delete Evidences Request",
     *     tags={"Evidences"},
     *     @OA\RequestBody(
     *         @OA\MediaType(
     *             mediaType="application/json",
     *             @OA\Schema(ref="#/components/schemas/DeleteEvidencesRequest")
     *         )
     *     ),
     *     @OA\Response(
     *          response=200,
     *          description="JSON API response",
     *          @OA\MediaType(
     *             mediaType="application/json",
     *             @OA\Schema(ref="#/components/schemas/DeleteEvidencesResponse")
     *         )
     *     )
     * )
     */ 
    protected function Delete(array &$data)
    {
        if (!isset($data['id'])) {
            echo $this->Response()->setErrorMessage("Evidence ID is required");
            return;
        }

        $evidence = new Evidence($data['id'], $this->_organization);
        $this->_evidenceDLL->Delete($evidence);
        echo $this->Response()->setStatus($evidence->_response)->setMessage($evidence->_message);
    }
```

Then, inside \Requests\Evidences\delete.inc:

```
<?php 

use OpenApi\Annotations as OA;

/**
 * @OA\Schema(
 *      schema="DeleteEvidencesRequest",
 *      title="Delete Evidences Request",
 *      @OA\Property(
 *          property="object",
 *          type="string",
 *          example="evidence"
 *      ),
 *      @OA\Property(
 *          property="action",
 *          type="string",
 *          example="delete"
 *      ),
 *      @OA\Property(
 *          property="data",
 *          type="object",
 *              @OA\Items(
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                      property="id",
 *                      type="string",
 *                      example="60"
 *                  ),
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                      property="entity_id",
 *                      type="string",
 *                      example="177"
 *                  ),
  *                 @OA\Property(
 *                      property="entity_type",
 *                      type="string",
 *                      example="task"
 *                  ),
 *              ),
 *      ),
 *      @OA\Property(
 *          property="organization",
 *          type="string",
 *          example="1"
 *      ),
 *      @OA\Property(
 *          property="site",
 *          oneOf={
 *              @OA\Schema(type="string"),
 *              @OA\Schema(type="boolean"),
 *          },
 *          example="1 | false"
 *      )
 * )
 */
class DeleteEvidencesRequest
{

}
```

As you can see, the names are correct, but for some reason, it does not appear on swagger editor:

[image]

The only shown is another schema from the same.
Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

"Unable to merge @OA\Post() ... "

This can happen because of duplicated 'path="/delete"'. Check all 'paths'.